# how to add graphics.h to code blocks in ubuntu ?

Tags: c++, compiler, code-blocks

I have installed the codeblocks from ubuntu software center and used good enough time no problem but when i try to access functions from graphics.h library I'm getting errors so please help me adding the graphics.h from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/ to the code::blocks. 
Thanking you , guys!

Answer (score 1):

WinBGIm graphics library is only for windows.

Possible options:

- use original Pascal graphics library (with Pascal language obviously)
- use different graphics library with C++
- use winbgim with C++, but cross-compile the code of the program to get a windows binary and run it in wine

**edit**

There are newer implementations of BGI graph library: SDL_bgi and libXbgi.

Site: http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/#download

Get the package *sdl-bgi_2.0.2-1_i386.deb* and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i sdl-bgi_2.0.2-1_i386.deb
```

Or alternatively, if you want to have a 64 bit version, then get the sources - it is the *SDL_bgi-2.0.2.tar.gz* archive. And compile + install them:

```
cd src
make
sudo checkinstall
```

To compile your program from command line using SDL_bgi, make sure that it includes the 'SDL_bgi.h' header file. Then:

```
gcc -o program program.c -lSDL_bgi -lSDL2
```

But you are using Code::Blocks, so you'll have to add `SDL_bgi` and `SDL2` to something like 'Link Libraries' in the project parameters.

If you have some non-crossplatform includes, then surround them with `ifndef __linux__` directives:

```
#ifndef __linux__
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#endif /* __linux__ */
```

Comment: I do not understand anything.

Comment: @A.B., the answer or the question? Probably they have to do some project at the university using C and winbgim . In the past there was Pascal with its 'graph' library. Then it was replaced by C and a port of the 'graph' library to windows (using GDI or something like that); port is called winbgim.

Comment: I appreciate for your your answer but can u be specific in answering directly? like in place of graphics.h or to make use similar kind of functions in code::blocks do v have any other alternatives ?

Comment: Wow, I've suddenly found two possible replacements: SDL_bgi and libXbgi. Added to the answer.